# PHPUnit Test case on POST endpoint returns 400

Tags: php, api, rest, class, symfony

I created a simple controller post endpoint which works fine with postman, but phpunit test case does fail and doesnt return expected 201 code

This is my controller in which I created simple post endpoint

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use App\Entity\User;

class UserController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/api/users", name="user", methods="POST")
     */
    public function post(Request $request): Response
    {
        $users = $request->toArray()['users'];//request body
        $usersArray = array('users'=>array());//response body
        $api_key = "d195e8fb160ff29935bce1fe6772253b18ac92d6b74f1f7407c8cbafbf439d3e";
//        $api_key = $request->headers->get('api-key');

        if($api_key && hash('sha256', 'testtest') === $api_key){

            foreach($users as $user){
                $newUser = new User();
                $newUser->setFirstName($user['first_name']);
                $newUser->setLastName($user['last_name']);
                $newUser->getFullName();
                array_push($usersArray['users'], $newUser);
            }

            return new Response(
                json_encode($usersArray),
                JsonResponse::HTTP_CREATED
            );
        }
        else {
            return new JsonResponse(
                ["Message" => "Api_key 'd195e8fb160ff29935bce1fe6772253b18ac92d6b74f1f7407c8cbafbf439d3e' is either incorrect or empty"],
                JsonResponse::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED
            );
        }

    }
}
```

This is my class

```
namespace App\Entity;

class User
{
    private $first_name;

    private $last_name;

    public $full_name;

    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->first_name;
    }

    public function setFirstName($first_name)
    {
        $this->first_name = $first_name;
    }

    public function getLastName()
    {
        return $this->last_name;
    }

    public function setLastName($last_name)
    {
        $this->last_name = $last_name;
    }


    public function getFullName()
    {
        return $this->full_name = $this->getFirstName()." ".$this->getLastName();;
    }
}
```

This is the test

```
<?php


namespace App\Tests;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class UserControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testUser()
    {
        $client = self::createClient();
        $client->request('POST', '/api/users', ['json' => [
            'users' => ['first_name'=>'Abraomas','last_name'=>'Linkolnas'],['first_name'=>'Abraomas','last_name'=>'Linkolnas']]
        ]);
        $this->assertEquals(201, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

This is what I get when I run `php bin/phpunit`

```
Testing Project Test Suite
F                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 463 ms, Memory: 20.00 MB

There was 1 failure:

1) App\Tests\UserControllerTest::testUser
Failed asserting that 400 matches expected 201.

D:\Users\Gediminas\Desktop\Symfony\tlb-final\tests\UserControllerTest.php:16

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.

Other deprecation notices (1)

  1x: Since symfony/monolog-bridge 5.2: Passing an actionLevel (int|string) as constructor's 3rd argument of "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\FingersCrossed\HttpCodeActivationStrategy" is deprecated, "Monolog\Handler\FingersCrossed\A
ctivationStrategyInterface" expected.
    1x in UserControllerTest::testUser from App\Tests
```

In the postman this post endpoint works fine with
Request body

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "first_name": "Abraomas",
            "last_name": "Braomas"
        },
        {
            "first_name": "Braomas",
            "last_name": "Abraomas"
        }
    ]
}
```

Response body

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "full_name": "Abraomas Braomas"
        },
        {
            "full_name": "Braomas Abraomas"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all try if this will work

```
$this->client->request(
    'POST', 
    '/api/users',  
    [],
    [],
    ['CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'],
    '{"users":[{"first_name":"Abraomas","last_name":"Braomas"},{"first_name":"Braomas","last_name":"Abraomas"}]}'
);
```

if so then try previous example but don't user `json` key in array and add content type manually

But the first thing You should do every time is to know how to find the problem and how to debug it. And pretty obvious is that Your problem lies somewhere at the begining of You action

```
$users = $request->toArray()['users'];//request body
```

Why just not simply add `dd($request->toArray());` after this assignment and check what You will see when test will run ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code that you have provided, your unit test seems to have an error - `users` array has to store both its array elements.

```
public function testUser()
{
  $client = self::createClient();
  $client->request('POST', '/api/users', ['json' => [
     'users' => [
      ['first_name'=>'Abraomas','last_name'=>'Linkolnas'], 
      ['first_name'=>'Abraomas','last_name'=>'Linkolnas']
     ]
    ]
  ]);

  $this->assertEquals(201, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
}
```

Comment: It does still return the same thing failure